# pass argument as a wildcard to node/add/Article/560012

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes, organic-groups

Case :

I do have a Article-share content type , it does contain a node reference to type "Article" , now this is my scenario :

- user selects a node of type Article
- he redirects to node/add/Article share
- now in this form I want the selected coupon shows up in the form automatically so the user wont need to fill this field again

[image]

Some more deails:

- I have a content type called "Article-Share".
- This type has a reference field to Node type "Article".
- I want my content creation form for type "Article Share" to use wildcards to automatically fill "Article Link".

Any suggestions how I can do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var urlVar =  window.location.pathname.split('/');
  if(urlVar[4]=='coupon-share' && urlVar[5]!=''){
    jQuery("#edit-field-user-coupon-link-und").val(urlVar[5]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a module for that but it's easy :

the scenario is this : 
on screen 1 , you've got a form which contains a select list , when user submits this form , will redirects to a content creation form , the important thing is that the coupon id must be passed to it .

so the solution :

you will have a submission function for your first screen form

```
function first_screen_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //enter some codes here to get nid of selected coupon
  //.
  //.
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/coupon-share/'. $nid;
  drupal_redirect_form($form_state);//this will redirects you to form and passes the nid
}
```

now you must alter the node creation form :

```
//Implement hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()     
function YourModuleName_form_node_form_alter(){
  if(isset($form['type']) && isset($form['#node'])) {
    $type = $form['#node']->type;
    switch($type) :
        case 'coupon-share':
          $passedNid = arg(3);
          $passedNode = node_load($passedNid);
          //now you have the coupon node available here and can fill your field with it
          //.
          //.
          breake;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like you want the [Entityreference prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module.

"Allow prepopulating any Entity reference field via URL"

From the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/entityreference_prepopulate/tree/README.txt):

```
Usage
=====
In order to pre-populate an entity reference field you have to supply the
parameter in the URL.

The structure is
node/add/article?[field_ref]=[id]

Where [field_ref] is the name of the entity reference field and [id] is
the id of the entity being referenced.

Examples:
node/add/article?field_foo=1
node/add/page?field_bar=1,2,3
```